# Angularfire2 v5 & Ionic 3 How to create Core Module?

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire

I am trying to implement this: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/#Generate-a-Core-Module-Optional

To my Ionic 3 project.

What is the "Ionic" way to implement the idea of a Code Module like they did in Angular5 tutorial?
When trying to run the code

```
ng g module core
```

I am getting the error:

```
Unable to find any apps in `.angular-cli.json`.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to the folder where you created the ionic app and run `ionic g page core`, ionic will generate a module for that `Core` page.

At this time ionic doesn't provides a `generate module` command. But with a `generate page` it will create a `module`.

[Here you have the list of commands](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/)